# Extracting values based on other column

Tags: r

I have this data in R.

```
Stops   Reasons
1       Pollution
NA      Pesticide
NA      Pesticide
0       NA
0       NA
```

I want to extract the values of the column Reasons based on the column Stops(when this one is 1). But when I do that it is also extracting the values of Reasons, where Stops has NA.

So I'm getting

```
Reasons
Pollution
Pesticide
Pesticide
```

But I only want

```
Reasons
Pollution
```

I did this

```
reasons=dataW$Reason[dataW$Stops==1]
```

or

```
reasons= dataW[dataW$Stops==1, "Reasons"]
```

But I don't know what else is missing. 
Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Wrap the condition in `which`: `dataW$Reason[which(dataW$Stops==1)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be due to the `NA` elements which return NA with the `==`.  We can use `%in%`

```
dataW$Reason[dataW$Stops %in% 1]
#[1] "Pollution"
```

---

Or use `is.na` to fix the OP's code

```
dataW$Reason[dataW$Stops == 1 & !is.na(dataW$Stops)]
#[1] "Pollution"
```

#### data

```
dataW <- structure(list(Stops = c(1L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L), Reasons = c("Pollution", 
"Pesticide", "Pesticide", NA, NA)), .Names = c("Stops", "Reasons"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to exclude `NA`s when subsetting is to use the `subset` function

```
subset(dataW, Stops == 1)$Reasons
```

Output Comparison

```
dataW <- data.table::fread("
Stops   Reasons
1       Pollution
NA      Pesticide
NA      Pesticide
0       NA
0       NA
", data.table = F)

dataW$Reason[dataW$Stops == 1]
# [1] "Pollution" NA          NA  
subset(dataW, Stops == 1)$Reasons
# [1] "Pollution"
```